# Need a step-by-step solution to this

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given a first order differential equation $$\frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{dx} - \frac{2}{x^2}y = x\cos x,$$ obtain the general solution using the method of integrating factor

Comment: Just divide by $x$, then the left side is a complete differential.

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: @LutzL Don't you mean multiply?

Comment: No, as $(y/x^2)'=y'/x^2-2y/x^3=\cos x$.

Answer (score 4):

**HINTS:**

Write $$\frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{dx} - \frac{2}{x^2}y = x\cos x\implies \frac{dy}{dx} - \frac{2}{x}y = x^2\cos x$$ Now let $$P(x)=-\frac2x,\quad Q(x)=x^2\cos x$$ and your integrating factor is $$I(x)=\exp\left(\int P(x)\,dx\right)$$ Can you continue?

Comment: just wanted to see if it tallies with what i did. Sorry it was an assignment and I had no one to ask. thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{dx} - \frac{2}{x^2}y = x\cos x,$$
$$\mu\frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{dx} - \mu\frac{2}{x^2}y = \mu  x\cos x,$$

$$(\mu\frac{1}{x})' = -\mu\frac{2}{x^2}$$
Integrate to get $\mu$
$$z' = -z\frac{2}{x}$$
$$\ln z= -2 \ln x$$
$$\mu\frac{1}{x}= x^{-2 }$$
$$\mu= x^{-1 }$$

Multiply both side by $\mu$

$$\mu\frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{dx} - \mu\frac{2}{x^2}y = \mu  x\cos x,$$
$$\frac{1}{x^2}y' - \frac{2}{x^3}y = \cos x,$$
$$(\frac{1}{x^2}y )' = \cos x$$
Integrate
$$(\frac{1}{x^2}y ) = \sin x+K$$
$$y  = x^2(\sin x+K)$$